# Inkscape rotation unexpectedly modifies rectangle coordinates

Tags: svg, inkscape

I use Inkscape to create levels for my game. My problem is: I create rectangle and when I want to rotate it, it is changing the (x,y) position of the rectangle.

[Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7raWns6Dsm0) of the coordinates changing in the object properties dialogue box. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: This is probably best on SuperUser, have asked for it to be moved.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates of an object is the lower left corner its bounding box (the smallest rectangle with edges parallel to the coordinate axes that contains the object). This bounding box is displayed in dashed lines and in your video you can see, how (and why) it changes when you rotate the square. If you rotate a square by a multiple of 90°, its coordinates do not change, since the bounding box is unaffected.

Comment: thank you.. Can you give me an example of how can i fix it thanks

Comment: how to get right coordinates from all this. Im parsing to create body so i need to get exact position

Comment: Could you specify, what exactly you need or consider to be “the right coordinates”? Whatever it is, you most probably will either have to evaluate the transformation matrix or convert the rectangle to a path (so you can directly access its nodes).

Answer (score 0):

that may because of the point of origin of the object set to left lower corner instead of its center, try if converting the object to a path helps